# tooltips on Svelte chart made with Layer Cake?

Tags: tooltip, svelte

I'm trying to add tooltips to a chart I made with [Layer Cake](https://layercake.graphics/), the graphics framework for Svelte. I looked at the Map example on the Layer Cake site, as that one has tooltips, but I can't figure out how to adapt for my bar chart.

I can't even get a string to show up, much less any data. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I think I must be missing something pretty obvious.

Below is a minimal example with dummy data.

You can see the code working in this REPL:
https://svelte.dev/repl/e8bb579754e6405ea19363b5d13d7f54?version=3.55.1

Thanks!

App.svelte:

```
    <script>
      import { LayerCake, Svg, Html } from "layercake";
      import Bar from "./Bar.svelte";
      import AxisX from "./AxisX.svelte";
      import AxisY from "./AxisY.svelte";
      import Tooltip from "./Tooltip.html.svelte";
      import { scaleBand } from "d3-scale";

      let data = [
          {
            fruit: "Apple",
            number: 364,
          },
          {
            fruit: "Banana",
            number: 263,
          },
          {
            fruit: "Mango",
            number: 872,
          },
          {
            fruit: "Pear",
            number: 156,
          },
        ]
      
      data.forEach((d) => {
        d[xKey] = +d[xKey];
      });

      const xKey = "number";
      const yKey = "fruit";

      let evt;
      let hideTooltip = false;
    </script>

        <div class="chart-container">
          <LayerCake
            padding={{ top: 20, bottom: 80, left: 60, right:40 }}
            x={xKey}
            y={yKey}
            yScale={scaleBand().paddingInner([0.15])}
            xDomain={[0, null]}
            data={data}
          >
            <Svg>
              <AxisX gridlines={true} baseline={true} snapTicks={true} ticks="4" />
              <AxisY gridlines={false} />
              <Bar 
              />
            </Svg>
            <Html
          pointerEvents={false}
        >
          {#if hideTooltip !== true}
            <Tooltip
              {evt}
            >
              {@const tooltipData = {data}}
              {#each Object.entries(tooltipData) as [key, value]}
              {console.log('tooltipData',tooltipData)}
                <div class="row">hi is this showing up?</div>
              {/each}
            </Tooltip>
          {/if}
        </Html>
          </LayerCake>
        </div>
    <style>
      .chart-container {
        width: 600px;
        height: 300px;
      }
    </style>
```

The other components are taken directly from the LayerCake framework.

Comment: Do **not** just link off-site to some code. Create a *minimal* example and include all relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: @H.B. Sure, updated. Though I think it's easier to see the code in the REPL, where it compiles...

Comment: There is no problem with linking to a REPL in addition to that, I would recommend it, but the question has to function on its own so it does not become useless if/when the REPL is down.

Comment: Got it. I'll be sure to include the code in all future questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Most important thing was to add a dispatch event in the Bar component, and create mouseover, movemove, focus events for the rects there.

Updated REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/09725c92e4104d0cad53d0387a762269?version=3.55.1

App.svelte:

```
    <script>
      import { LayerCake, Svg, Html } from "layercake";
      import Bar from "./Bar.svelte";
      import AxisX from "./AxisX.svelte";
      import AxisY from "./AxisY.svelte";
      import Tooltip from "./Tooltip.html.svelte";
      import { scaleBand } from "d3-scale";

      let data = [
          {
            fruit: "Apple",
            number: 364,
          },
          {
            fruit: "Banana",
            number: 263,
          },
          {
            fruit: "Mango",
            number: 872,
          },
          {
            fruit: "Pear",
            number: 156,
          },
        ]
      
      data.forEach((d) => {
        d[xKey] = +d[xKey];
      });

      const xKey = "number";
      const yKey = "fruit";

      let evt;
      let hideTooltip = false;
    </script>

        <div id="chart-container">
          <LayerCake
            padding={{ top: 20, bottom: 80, left: 60, right:40 }}
            x={xKey}
            y={yKey}
            yScale={scaleBand().paddingInner([0.15])}
            xDomain={[0, null]}
            data={data}
          >
            <Svg>
              <AxisX gridlines={true} baseline={true} snapTicks={true} ticks="4" />
              <AxisY gridlines={false} />
              <Bar 
                  on:mousemove={event => evt = hideTooltip = event}
                  on:mouseout={() => (hideTooltip = true)}
              />
            </Svg>
            <Html
              pointerEvents={false}
            >
            {#if hideTooltip !== true}
              <Tooltip
                {evt}
                let:detail
              >
              {@const tooltipData = { ...detail.props }}
                    <div class="row">{tooltipData.fruit}: {tooltipData.number}</div>
              </Tooltip>
          {/if}
        </Html>
          </LayerCake>
        </div>
    <style>
      #chart-container {
        width: 600px;
        height: 300px;
      }
    </style>
```

Bar.svelte:

```
    <script>
        import { getContext, createEventDispatcher } from "svelte";

        const { data, xGet, yGet, xScale, yScale } = getContext('LayerCake');

        export let fill = '#ef4136';
        let hideTooltip = false;
      
        const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
        
        function handleMousemove(feature) {
          return function handleMousemoveFn(e) {
            raise(this);
            // When the element gets raised, it flashes 0,0 for a second so skip that
            if (e.layerX !== 0 && e.layerY !== 0) {
              dispatch("mousemove", { e });
            }
          };
        }

    </script>
      <g
      class="bar-group"
      on:mouseout={(e) => dispatch("mouseout")}
      on:blur={(e) => dispatch("mouseout")}
      >
        {#each $data as d, i}
          <rect
            class='group-rect'
            data-id="{i}"
            x="{$xScale.range()[0]}"
            y="{$yGet(d)}"
            height={$yScale.bandwidth()}
            width="{$xGet(d)}"
            {fill}              
            on:mouseover={(e) => dispatch("mousemove", { e, props: d })}
            on:focus={(e) => dispatch("mousemove", { e, props: d })}
            on:mousemove={(e) => handleMousemove(e, d)}
          ></rect>


        {/each}
      </g>
```

Tooltip.html.svelte, AxisY.svelte, and AxisX.svelte stay the same as they were (as they are in Layer Cake).